# When does a Pod get destroyed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, livenessprobe

Pod lifecycle is managed by Kubelet in data plane.

As per the definition: If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container

Pod is just a container with dedicated network namespace & IPC namespace with a sandbox container.

---

Say, if the Pod is single app container Pod, then upon liveness failure:

- Does kubelet kill the Pod?

or

- Does kubelet kill the container (only) within the Pod?

Comment: Since ["*Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes*"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/), I would expect that the **pod** gets destroyed and recreated.

Comment: @Turing85 So, if a Pod has two app containers, then liveness failure of one container will affect the other container, Is that correct?

Comment: I would assume so, yes. But - as I have written - this is an expectation of mine, not hard knowledge.

Comment: @Turing85 So, `livenessProbe` & `readinessProbe` is written at Pod level, but not container level?

Comment: No. [Probes are defined on container-level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). The evaluation/response, however, seems to be on pod-level. The example in above documentation shows that the **pod** has been restarted as response of the **container probe** failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kubelet uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container (**NOT** the entire Pod). If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and then the container may be restarted, however it depends on its [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy).

---

I've created a simple example to demonstrate how it works.

First, I've created an `app-1` Pod with two containers (`web` and `db`).
The `web` container has a liveness probe configured, which always fails because the `/healthz` path is not configured.

```
$ cat app-1.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: web
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
  - image: postgres
    name: db
    env:
    - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      value: example
```

After applying the above manifest and waiting some time, we can describe the `app-1` Pod to check that only the `web` container has been restarted and the `db` container is running without interruption:
**NOTE:** I only provided important information from the `kubectl describe pod app-1` command, not the entire output.

```
$ kubectl apply -f app-1.yml
pod/app-1 created
    
$ kubectl describe pod app-1
    
Name:         app-1
...
Containers:
  web:
...
    Restart Count:  4   <--- Note that the "web" container was restarted 4 times
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8080/healthz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
...
  db:
...
    Restart Count:  0   <--- Note that the "db" container works fine
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
...
  Normal   Killing    78s (x2 over 108s)   kubelet            Container web failed liveness probe, will be restarted
...
```

We can connect to the `db` container to see if it is running:
**NOTE:** We can use the `db` container even when restarting the `web` container.

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-1 -c db -- bash
root@app-1:/#
```

In contrast, after connecting to the `web` container, we can observe that the liveness probe restarts this container:

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-1 -c web -- bash
root@app-1:/# command terminated with exit code 137
```

Answer (score 1):

A pod is indeed the smallest element in Kubernetes, but that does not mean it is in fact "empty" without a container.

In order to spawn a pod and therefore the container elements needed to attach further containers a very small container is created using the `pause` image.
This is used to allocate an IP that is then used for the pod.
Afterward the init-containers or runtime container declared for the pod are started.

If the lifeness probe fails, the container is restarted. The pod survives this. This is even important: You might want to get the logs of the crashed/restarted container afterwards. This would not be possible, if the pod was destroyed and recreated.